# Linux Bash Error ": bad substitution" and doesn't specify a line where the error occurs

Tags: xml, bash, jira

I have a userdata script that adds a couple of files and one does it correctly, however the second file `server.xml` does not. After the bash script ran I looked at my `server.xml` file and it was empty- I looked at my `cloud-init-output.log` file and after the command that's supposed to add my server.xml file runs, it just says `: bad substitution`. Doesn't specify a certain line or anything.

Here's the portion of my **userdata script** that's supposed to add the `server.xml` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "===== Downloading EFS Util & botocore ====="
yum install -y amazon-efs-utils
pip3 install botocore

echo "===== Downloading Jira ====="
wget -O ~/jira.bin https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/downloads/binary/atlassian-jira-software-8.22.4-x64.bin

cat <<\EOF >> ~/jira.varfile
app.confHome=/var/atlassian/application-data/jira
app.install.service$Boolean=false
portChoice=custom
httpPort$Long=8080
rmiPort$Long=8443
launch.application$Boolean=false
sys.adminRights$Boolean=true
sys.confirmedUpdateInstallationString=false
sys.installationDir=/opt/atlassian/jira
sys.languageId=en
EOF

echo "done"
echo "===== Modify Jira Permissions ====="
chmod +x ~/jira.bin
echo "===== Start Jira Install ====="
sudo ~/jira.bin -q -varfile ~/jira.varfile
echo "==== Starting Jira ===="
sudo /opt/atlassian/jira/bin/startup.sh
echo "===== Cleaning up Jira Files ====="
rm -f ~/jira.bin
rm -f ~/jira.varfile
chmod 750 /opt/atlassian/jira/logs/

mkdir /var/sharedhome

echo "===== Mounting EFS ====="
echo "${efs_id}:/ /var/sharedhome efs _netdev,tls,iam,nofail 0 0" | tee -a /etc/fstab
mount -a

echo "===== Grabbing IP via SSM ====="
TOKEN=$(curl -s -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600")
INSTANCE_IP=$(wget --header="X-aws-ec2-metadata-token:$TOKEN" -qO- http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)

echo "===== Configuring cluster.properties ====="
echo -e "jira.node.id = node$RANDOM \njira.shared.home = /var/sharedhome \nehcache.listener.hostName = $INSTANCE_IP" | tee -a /var/atlassian/application-data/jira/cluster.properties

echo "===== Adding dbconfig.xml ====="
cat >/var/atlassian/application-data/jira/dbconfig.xml <<EOL 
${db_config} 
EOL
cat /var/atlassian/application-data/jira/dbconfig.xml

echo "===== Adding server.xml ====="
cat -v >/opt/atlassian/jira/conf/server.xml <<EOL 
${server_config} 
EOL
cat -v /opt/atlassian/jira/conf/server.xml
```

The reason I included my dbconfig.xml file is because I pass in the files the exact same way and for some reason it works for that file, but not my server.xml file.

Not sure if it helps, but here's my server.xml file as well:

**server.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<Server port="8443" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>

    <Service name="Catalina">
        <!--
         ==============================================================================================================
         DEFAULT - Direct connector with no proxy for unproxied access to Jira.

         If using a http/https proxy, comment out this connector.
         ==============================================================================================================
        -->

            <!-- Relaxing chars because of JRASERVER-67974 -->
            <!--
        <Connector port="8080" relaxedPathChars="[]|" relaxedQueryChars="[]|{}^&#x5c;&#x60;&quot;&lt;&gt;"
                   maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" connectionTimeout="20000" enableLookups="false"
                   maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" protocol="HTTP/1.1" useBodyEncodingForURI="true" redirectPort="8443"
                   acceptCount="100" disableUploadTimeout="true" bindOnInit="false"/>
        -->
        <!--
         ==============================================================================================================
         HTTP - Proxying Jira via Apache or Nginx over HTTP

         If you're proxying traffic to Jira over HTTP, uncomment the below connector and comment out the others.
         Ensure the proxyName and proxyPort are updated with the appropriate information if necessary as per the docs.

         See the following for more information:

            Apache - https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/4xQLM
            nginx  - https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/DAFmGQ
         ==============================================================================================================
        -->


        <Connector port="8080" relaxedPathChars="[]|" relaxedQueryChars="[]|{}^&#x5c;&#x60;&quot;&lt;&gt;"
                   maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" connectionTimeout="20000" enableLookups="false"
                   maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" protocol="HTTP/1.1" useBodyEncodingForURI="true" redirectPort="8443"
                   acceptCount="100" disableUploadTimeout="true" bindOnInit="false" scheme="https"
                   proxyName="<subdomain>.<domain>.com" proxyPort="443"/>


        <!--
         ==============================================================================================================
         HTTPS - Proxying Jira via Apache or Nginx over HTTPS

         If you're proxying traffic to Jira over HTTPS, uncomment the below connector and comment out the others.
         Ensure the proxyName and proxyPort are updated with the appropriate information if necessary as per the docs.

         See the following for more information:

            Apache - https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/PTT3MQ
            nginx  - https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/DAFmGQ
         ==============================================================================================================
        -->

        <!--
        <Connector port="8080" relaxedPathChars="[]|" relaxedQueryChars="[]|{}^&#x5c;&#x60;&quot;&lt;&gt;"
                   maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" connectionTimeout="20000" enableLookups="false"
                   maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" protocol="HTTP/1.1" useBodyEncodingForURI="true" redirectPort="8443"
                   acceptCount="100" disableUploadTimeout="true" bindOnInit="false" secure="true" scheme="https"
                   proxyName="<subdomain>.<domain>.com" proxyPort="443"/>
        -->

        <!--
         ==============================================================================================================
         AJP - Proxying Jira via Apache over HTTP or HTTPS

         If you're proxying traffic to Jira using the AJP protocol, uncomment the following connector line
         See the following for more information:

            Apache - https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/QiJ9MQ
         ==============================================================================================================
        -->

        <!--
        <Connector port="8009" URIEncoding="UTF-8" enableLookups="false" protocol="AJP/1.3"/>
        -->

        <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
            <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

                <Context path="" docBase="${catalina.home}/atlassian-jira" reloadable="false" useHttpOnly="true">
                    <Resource name="UserTransaction" auth="Container" type="javax.transaction.UserTransaction"
                              factory="org.objectweb.jotm.UserTransactionFactory" jotm.timeout="60"/>
                    <Manager pathname=""/>
                    <JarScanner scanManifest="false"/>
                    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.StuckThreadDetectionValve" threshold="120" />
                </Context>

            </Host>
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
                   pattern="%a %{jira.request.id}r %{jira.request.username}r %t &quot;%m %U%{sanitized.query}r %H&quot; %s %b %D &quot;%{sanitized.referer}r&quot; &quot;%{User-Agent}i&quot; &quot;%{jira.request.assession.id}r&quot;"/>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

I'm just confused why the server.xml file gives me that error, because it shows the file contents in my logs, along with the dbconfig.xml file, but only the server.xml file gives me that error **: bad substitution**.

For context, the variables in my userdata script for $`{db_config}` and `${server_config}` are there because that's how I pass in the file contents using Terraform. Terraform reads the files using the [file function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/file) and passes in the file contents to my userdata script.

Comment: That error message looks like it's been mangled by a carriage return or something similar. Try viewing the log with `cat -v` to make invisible/weird characters visible, and see if you can see more. (Using the same command to view the script file might also help.)

Comment: @GordonDavisson I tried `cat -v /var/log/cloud-init-output.log` and `cat -v /opt/atlassian/jira/conf/server.xml` and unfortunately got the same results. The error is still mangled and the server.xml file is completely empty. Also when my application gets installed the file `/opt/atlassian/jira/conf/server.xml` already exists, I'm basically just trying to overwrite the default contents with my own that I'm passing in. Not sure if that makes a difference, because my dbconfig.xml file, which works correctly, isn't overwritting any existing files and just creates a new one

Comment: Run your script with `-x` turned on, so that you can see the line where the error occurs.

Comment: The next debugging step I'd try is making sure you can capture error output from the script (one method is to put something like `exec 2>>/tmp/userdata-script.log` at the beginning), then put `set -x` in the script to get an execution trace and see what leads up to the error.

Comment: @GordonDavisson  I looked at the `userdata-script.log` and it just shows (in this order) `+ cat` >> `contents of the xml file` >> `: bad substitution` >> `+ cat /opt/atlassian/jira/conf/server.xml`. I tried to cat -v that as well and it still just shows `+ cat /opt/atlassian/jira/conf/server.xml` for the error

Comment: Does your script have a valid shebang on it, or how are you executing it? If it's not running as a bash script that could potentially cause issues.

Comment: @tjm3772 I went ahead and added the entire userdata script. I also tried this script with the `exec 2>>/tmp/userdata-script.log` and `set -x` as the 2nd and 3rd line in the script to try to get the full error message and I got the same results as before